# Xpath get an element that lies between two elements with specific attributes

Tags: xml, xpath, nokogiri, xpath-2.0

Example 1

```
   <w:r>
        <w:t>gene</w:t>
   </w:r>
   <w:ins>
        <w:t>s</w:t>
   </w:ins>
   <w:r>
        <w:t> </w:t> #I want to select this element
   </w:r>
   <w:del >
        <w:t>house</w:t>
   </w:del>
   <w:r>
        <w:t>had</w:t>
   </w:r>
   <w:r>
        <w:t> </w:t>  #I do not want to select this element
   </w:r>
   <w:ins >
        <w:t>under</w:t>
   </w:ins>
   <w:del>
        <w:t>in</w:t>
    </w:del>
    <w:r>
        <w:t> </w:t>  #I want to select this element
    </w:r>
    <w:ins>
        <w:t>the</w:t>
    </w:ins>
```

Example 2

```
  <w:r>
    <w:t>specific genes</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:ins>
      <w:t>;</w:t>
  </w:ins>
  <w:del>
      <w:t>,</w:t>
  </w:del>
  <w:r>
    <w:t> </w:t>  #I don't want to select this one
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>SO</w:t>
  </w:r>
```

The elements I wish to select are indicated above.  The w:r elements that contain a space must be directly preceded by a w:ins or w:del element and also must be directly followed by a w:ins or w:del element

I've started with the following expression but it does not take into account that preceding-sibling could be a w:del element. Similarly for the following-sibling. Also it must check the element just before or just after to see if its a w:ins or w:del element.

search("//w:r[. = ' ' and preceding-sibling::w:ins and following-sibling::w:del]")

However, this does not seem to work as it selects all w:r elements that contain a space.

I'm using Nokogiri.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to find the correct solution or at least one that works to give me the desired results:

```
search("//w:r[. = ' ' and following-sibling::*[position()=1][name()='w:del' or name()='w:ins']and preceding-sibling::*[position()=1][name()='w:del' or name()='w:ins']]")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following `xpath`:

```
//*[local-name()='r' and node()='' and preceding-sibling::*[local-name()='ins'] and following-sibling::*[local-name()='ins'] ]
```

**INPUTS:**

```
more example1.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns:w="http://so.com">
  <w:r>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">gene</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:ins>
    <w:r>
      <w:t>s</w:t>
    </w:r>
  </w:ins>
  <w:del>
    <w:r>
      <w:delText>,</w:delText>
    </w:r>
  </w:del>
  <w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve"/>  #I want to select this element
      </w:r>
  <w:ins>
    <w:r>
      <w:t>under</w:t>
    </w:r>
  </w:ins>
  <w:del>
    <w:r>
      <w:delText>in</w:delText>
    </w:r>
  </w:del>
  <w:r>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">both</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:del>
    <w:r>
      <w:delText xml:space="preserve">the</w:delText>
    </w:r>
  </w:del>
</root>
```

**2nd file:**

```
more example2.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns:w="http://so.com">
  <w:r>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">phenotypic specific genes</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:ins>
    <w:r>
      <w:t>;</w:t>
    </w:r>
  </w:ins>
  <w:del>
    <w:r w:rsidDel="00167AE4" w:rsidRPr="006C5D4F">
      <w:delText>,</w:delText>
    </w:r>
  </w:del>
  <w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve"/> #I don't want to select this one
  </w:r>
  <w:r w:rsidRPr="006C5D4F">
    <w:t>SOX9</w:t>
  </w:r>
</root>
```

**results:**

**example1.xml**

```
$xmllint --xpath "//*[local-name()='r' and node()='' and preceding-sibling::*[local-name()='ins'] and following-sibling::*[local-name()='ins'] ]" example1.xml
<w:r>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve"/>  #I want to select this element
</w:r>
```

**example2.xml**

```
$ xmllint --xpath "//*[local-name()='r' and node()='' and preceding-sibling::*[local-name()='ins'] and following-sibling::*[local-name()='ins'] ]" example2.xml 
XPath set is empty
```

Comment: Allan I tried your code on my full file and it matched 52 segments when it should only match one.

Comment: Actually this gets me close when I tried it but I'm getting two segments when I should only get one. One of the segments is not followed by an w:ins or a w:del but by a w:r element which I don't want.